# Move abroad for internship

Tags: internship, student, expectations

I am a Student in my 20s who’s recently moved abroad to do an internship. I have in the past year been in the USA to do an exchange semester there, and loved it. Therefore I applied to European (I am from Europe) companies for an internship, and was given an internship at a very large, highly reputable company that have been one of my dream companies for a long time.

I arrived here, and things have been very different from what I expected. I was expecting, as talked about during the interview, that I would be working alongside highly experienced engineers, get to view actual hardware, build prototypes and similar. However, almost everyone is working from home and there is no viewing of actual hardware due to severe restrictions on company designs.

I am not feeling as if I am making progress or working towards a goal, but rather learning in a chaotic way with bits and pieces. I have addressed this with my supervisor, and Been told that I am doing well and learning as is intended.

Performing this internship puts a severe toll on me as I am a full time student to the side, but I am also disciplined and believed this to be such a great opportunity that 6 months of hard work would be worth it.

I have entirely lost my ‘spark’ here, and dread coming to work and only look forward to going home. At university, this was completely the other way around.

I have requested information about the way ahead, which did not paint a picture supporting to stay.

Additionally, social life outside work is completely absent, worsened by covid, and student organizations do not wish to help as I am not an exchange student officially. I have experienced this strain of loneliness before, and do not wish to repeat it.

I have many trustworthy friends and supporting family, but wish to reach out here due to the seriousness of the site and experience people here have. Despite the question being open for opinion.

I am seriously considering to pull the plug on this, and go back home to find back to the spark I used to have.

I have almost completely lost my “will to act”, after fighting to make it now for 1 month. As a surplus, all administrative things have and remains extremely difficult and complicated, and the company is very little helpful about the situation.

I am two breaths away from ordering an airline ticket and delivering my resignation, but wish to ask still, and make sure my decision is rational and not in affect.

As mentioned, I have experienced “homesickness” before in the USA, where it resolved after some time whereas here it has worsened. I have been here 1 month now.

My contract allows for extremely simple resignation the first month, with a few days remaining. If I wait, I will commit to another month.

Please share your inputs on this.

Comment: Sorry to hear you are struggling, but this is only a decision you can make - none of us can weigh up all the factors here, many of which are entirely personal to you.

Comment: @PhilipKendall unfortunately yes, I guess I am only looking to hear if someone has found themselves in a similar position with expections vs reality for a dream job of company. It also does not look pretty that I would “give up” such an opportunity, which I believed before coming here and what others think to be an absolutely fairytale - which it entirely is not. However I am inclined to support my own well being first. There is nothing about my duties that remind me of the company i am working for, other than the wallpaper of my company laptop.

Comment: All I would say is that your first professional job is never what you expect it will be. It sucks and takes ages to get to the point where the work feels useful. Don't discount the impacts of COVID, so certainly speak with your manager to determine when/if what was discussed in the interview can be delivered.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned - you are working along side experienced engineers in a highly reputable company, which can be a remarkable experience for your portfolio when you eventually go onto job hunting after your graduation.

However, it is difficult for us to advice you if you should resign from this internship as you were taking a mental toll on things. Perhaps talk to your academic supervisor or a co-worker whom you respect and seek their advice.

> I am not feeling as if I am making progress or working towards a goal, but rather learning in a chaotic way with bits and pieces.

I feel your pain. With regards to learning, if you eventually decides to commit, perhaps a change of mindset will help you to endure better throughout this journey. That is - when it comes to learning, don't lose yourself in the chores and make good use of the time after work to do active learning.

You can enroll yourself into online courses in topics related to your industry on Coursera/Udemy/Udacity, allocate time to do active learning and make every opportunity to apply what you learnt into your work. That way you make full use of your internship as a learning platform and you'll gain certification of completion on each courses you finished throughout this 6 months which you can pad onto your Linkedin profile.